# How to get multiple values on("input") and store them in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating an installation script, before executing the script I want to test entered credentials. I want to get these values directly before posting, then post through ajax to check if credentials works fine. I am stuck at storing them in array since these values changes everytime they get updated and array gets filled with trash data.

What would be the best method to store final or latest data in an array before posting them?

```js
var host = '',
db = '',
user = '',
pass = '';

$("#host").on("input", function() {
   host = $(this).val();
   arr.push(host);
   
   $("#host_r").text($(this).val()); //just to debug
   console.log(arr);
});

$("#db").on("input", function() {
   db = $(this).val();
   arr.push(db);

   $("#db_r").text($(this).val()); //just to debug
   console.log(arr);

});

$("#user").on("input", function() {
   user = $(this).val();
   arr.push(user);

   $("#user_r").text($(this).val()); //just to debug
   console.log(arr);

});

$("#pass").on("input", function() {
   pass = $(this).val();
   arr.push(pass);
   
   $("#pass_r").text($(this).val()); //just to debug
   console.log(arr);
});

var arr = new Array;



console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="host" id="host" required>
<input name="db" id="db" required>
<input name="user" id="user" required>
<input name="pass" id="pass" required>

<br/>
Host
<div id="host_r"></div>
DB
<div id="db_r"></div>
User
<div id="user_r"></div>
Pass
<div id="pass_r"></div>
Array
<div id="array"></div>
```

Comment: What's wrong with how you are currently doing it?

Comment: I am trying to store `final` variables to `array`

Comment: Where is your posting functionality? Push your variables there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To DRY this up you can put all the fields in a `<form>` element. You can then call `serializeArray()` on that form when it's submit, which you can send in an AJAX request.

You can also turn the logic which puts the field's values in to a related `div` by matching them by `name` to `id` in to a single line.

Try this:

```js
$('form').on('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let arr = $(e.target).serializeArray();
  console.log(arr);
  
  // send the array in an AJAX request here...
});


// for debugging, show values in the DOM
$('.field').on('input', e => $('#' + e.target.name).text(e.target.value));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input name="host" class="field" required />
  <input name="db" class="field" required />
  <input name="user" class="field" required />
  <input name="pass" class="field" required />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<br/> 
Host <div id="host"></div>
DB <div id="db"></div>
User <div id="user"></div>
Pass <div id="pass"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the idea! The thing is, these values are defined on actual form, I need to set another form to init ajax call. Do you think its clean to get array data from another forms input? instead of `$(e.target).serializeArray();` using  `$("#mainForm").serializeArray();`?

Comment: Yeah, that's absolutely fine. Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

The `input` event happens on each character that the user types, so you'll got lots of extra values in the array, with all the incomplete values that the user typed along the way. Also, the order of the array will depend on the order that the user filled in the fields.

You should add a separate submit button, and fill in the array with all the inputs at once when the user clicks this. Then you'll get the final values and they'll be in a consistent order.

```js
var host = '',
db = '',
user = '',
pass = '';

$("#host").on("input", function() {
   host = $(this).val();
   
   $("#host_r").text($(this).val()); //just to debug
});

$("#db").on("input", function() {
   db = $(this).val();

   $("#db_r").text($(this).val()); //just to debug
});

$("#user").on("input", function() {
   user = $(this).val();

   $("#user_r").text($(this).val()); //just to debug
});

$("#pass").on("input", function() {
   pass = $(this).val();
   
   $("#pass_r").text($(this).val()); //just to debug
});

var arr;

$("#submit").click(function() {
  arr = [host, db, user, pass];
  console.log(arr);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="host" id="host" required>
<input name="db" id="db" required>
<input name="user" id="user" required>
<input name="pass" id="pass" required>
<br>
<button id="submit">Done</button>
<br/>
Host
<div id="host_r"></div>
DB
<div id="db_r"></div>
User
<div id="user_r"></div>
Pass
<div id="pass_r"></div>
Array
<div id="array"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using `serializeArray()`. It will give you an object with name:value pairs. To get only values as array you may use `map()`. See the button click action.

```js
$('input').keyup(function(){
   var arr = $("#form").serializeArray();
   $('#res').html('');
     $.each(arr, function(i, field){
        $("#res").append(field.name + ": " + field.value + "<br />");
     });
});

$('#get_values').click(function(){
  var myobj = $("#form").serializeArray();
  var myarr = myobj.map(x => x.value);
  console.log(myarr);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
<input name="host" id="host" required>
<input name="db" id="db" required>
<input name="user" id="user" required>
<input name="pass" id="pass" required>
</form>
<br />
<button id="get_values">Get Values</button>
<br />
<div id="res" style="height:100px"></div>
```